# API Platform cursor based pagination with graphql

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Working on a mongodb + graphql api, it seems that no matter how I configure the pagination, it always returns the same cursor for each edges. On top of that, I tried to change the direction of the pagination but it does not reflect in the results.

Here is the global configuration:

```yaml
api_platform:
    show_webby: false
    enable_swagger: false
    enable_swagger_ui: false
    enable_re_doc: false
    enable_entrypoint: false
    enable_docs: false
    enable_profiler: false
    graphql:
        graphql_playground:
            enabled: false
        collection:
            pagination:
                enabled: false
```

The resource:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Document;

use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Odm\Filter\OrderFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Odm\Filter\RangeFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GraphQl\QueryCollection;
use App\Repository\StatusRepository;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Types\Type;

#[ODM\Document(repositoryClass: StatusRepository::class)]
#[ODM\UniqueIndex(keys: ['vessel.id' => 'asc', 'time' => 'asc'])]
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [],
    paginationViaCursor: [
        ['field' => 'numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination', 'direction' => 'DESC']
    ],
    paginationEnabled: true,
    paginationPartial: true,
    paginationType: 'cursor',
    graphQlOperations: [
        new QueryCollection(
            security: 'is_granted("ROLE_CURRENT_STATUS_READ")',
            name: 'current',
        ),
    ],
)]
#[ApiFilter(RangeFilter::class, properties: ['numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination'])]
#[ApiFilter(OrderFilter::class, properties: ['numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination' => 'DESC'])]
class Status
{
    public function __construct(
        #[ODM\Id(type: Type::STRING, strategy: 'NONE')]
        private readonly string $id,
        #[ODM\Field(type: Type::INT)]
        private readonly int $numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination,
    ) {
    }

    public function getId(): string
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getNumericFieldForCursorBasedPagination(): int
    {
        return $this->numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination;
    }
}
```

The result:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "currentStatuses": {
      "totalCount": 10,
      "pageInfo": {
        "startCursor": "MA==",
        "endCursor": "NA==",
        "hasPreviousPage": false,
        "hasNextPage": true
      },
      "edges": [
        {
          "cursor": "MA==",
          "node": {
            "id": "\/api\/statuses\/018d78c4-2042-7ae0-9134-f394ab2d9f48",
            "_id": "018d78c4-2042-7ae0-9134-f394ab2d9f48",
            "numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination": 5,
          }
        },
        {
          "cursor": "MQ==",
          "node": {
            "id": "\/api\/statuses\/018d78c4-20cd-7475-bc9c-1b24571c7a7d",
            "_id": "018d78c4-20cd-7475-bc9c-1b24571c7a7d",
            "numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination": 4,
          }
        },
        {
          "cursor": "Mg==",
          "node": {
            "id": "\/api\/statuses\/018d78c4-20d1-7183-b73a-e89a67bf30cb",
            "_id": "018d78c4-20d1-7183-b73a-e89a67bf30cb",
            "numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination": 12,
          }
        },
        {
          "cursor": "Mw==",
          "node": {
            "id": "\/api\/statuses\/018d78c4-20d4-7619-8681-47e221006801",
            "_id": "018d78c4-20d4-7619-8681-47e221006801",
            "numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination": 19,
          }
        },
        {
          "cursor": "NA==",
          "node": {
            "id": "\/api\/statuses\/018d78c4-20d7-7e7f-a661-95abdba696ff",
            "_id": "018d78c4-20d7-7e7f-a661-95abdba696ff",
            "numericFieldForCursorBasedPagination": 11,
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see the pagination's direction is not taken into account. The cursor of each edges are always the same (MA==, MQ==, Mg==, ...) no matter the data it is linked to. I would think that cursor would be based of the field set in the `paginationViaCursor` , or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the cursor based pagination has not been implemented in api platform **for graphql**. The options existed, but has been removed in this PR https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/5333